# Win 7: How can I resize a window to make it much bigger than my screen?

Tags: windows-7, window, window-manager

I have a window that I'd like to make much bigger than my physical screen (explanation of why below). I hit `Alt+Space, M`, and then press the Up arrow to move the title bar above the physical top of my screen. However, when I press Enter to set it, the title bar snaps back to the top of my screen. How can I prevent this from happening?

**Background**: I want to get a hi-res image of a neighborhood map so that it can be printed to a poster. Google Earth has a "Save as JPG" feature, which will save the map in the window to a file. The bigger the window, the bigger the JPG; so, I'm trying to make the window as big as I can. Alternate suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that specific purpose, what you need is **[Google Map Saver](http://www.codres.de/google-map-saver)**.

Google Map Saver (GMS) offers you an easy and free way to download big Google Maps on your PC as JPEG, PNG-8, PNG-24, BMP or Targa files. GMS is light (only ~400 KBytes) and very easy to run since doesn’t have an installer. You can save maps up to 12000 x 12000 pixels!

[image]

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Dour High Arch's method, but the easiest way to do this (which I've done before) is to use Windows 7's in-built Snipping Tool and create heaps of snips then use a [panorama stitching program](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=free+panorama+software&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) like [AutoStitch](http://cvlab.epfl.ch/~brown/autostitch/autostitch.html) or [Microsoft Image Composite Editor](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/groups/ivm/ice/) to automatically join them all. Then crop it using a graphics editing program (Paint should suffice).

*Some screenshots of the process...*

The collected snips

[image]

Let panorama software join it for you

[image]

and the full thing:

[image]

*(To view images in full, right click and click View)*

Answer (score 2):

I see that you got all the answers that you needed for your particular map printing issue. However, in case you need to resize a window to a size larger than the screen in the future, you can use an application called ScreenSpace.

ScreenSpace is a small app that I have developed http://www.dandeware.com/products/, mainly aimed at netbook to solve the problems created by small screens. But it works with any computer running Windows XP and Windows 7, and with any screen resolution. Actually, I have just posted an answer to a similar question, so you can learn more about it [here](https://superuser.com/questions/85362/looking-for-an-application-that-scrolls-or-pans-netbook-screens-running-windows/139155#139155).

Also, just like I offered the author of that question I answered, let me know if you want to try ScreenSpace, I'll give you a license so that you can use all the features.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried any myself but there are various virtual desktop managers for Windows. You should be able to find one that allows windows to overlap across virtual desktops.

Answer (score 1):

You can try GiMeSpace Desktop Extender.
Easy and powerful without any size limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate method: Alt-PrintScreen and page horizontally and vertically repeatedly to save screen shots of the area you want to keep. Stitch the multiple images into a single one in a graphics editor, then save the stitched image as a .jpg.