# Drag a window beyond screen that is not resizable with custom scaled text turned on

Tags: windows-10, scaling, resizing

[image: screenshot]

Alt+Space+M doesn't work either, and I can't resize the window because it reverts to its original position when I press enter, I have custom scaled text turned on and the window is too big to fit on the whole screen, and turning it off does fix the problem, but I don't want to turn it off. Neither does moving or auto-hiding the taskbar fix anything.

Comment: A developer has complete control over what the size of a window within an application can be on Windows.  What exactly is your question l?

Comment: I have clarified my question in an edit.

Comment: I have found what I needed. [Here](https://superuser.com/a/85365/238932) is a related question.